# Bring back the podcast

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, podcast

This is my official request for the podcast to come back.

A lot has happened since it went to hiatus that would be worth talking about, and the team is large enough and with so many different areas (development, advertising, careers, community coordination) that the podcast could feature a different member each week, making it not necessary for Jeff and Joel to be available for it, and keeping it fresh with topics.

Also, I run out of interesting audiobooks for the days I don't bring my bike to work.

<sub>Note: relate to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56943/any-thought-of-bringing-back-the-podcast), but I'm suggesting a direction it could take different than the podcast 1.0</sub>

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42247/what-ideas-are-out-there-for-the-new-podcast/74575

Comment: other good podcasts for 10k users only http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644/what-good-technology-podcasts-are-out-there and not http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/282/what-are-the-best-podcasts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[According to Joel](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/welcome-valued-associate-alex-miller/), it appears that the podcasts will be returning:

> In the coming months you’ll see
> several amazing things that Alex has
> started doing, including the
> resurgence of Stack Overflow DevDays,
> **the renewal of my podcast with Jeff**, and an amazing thing, still
> secret, involving unicorns.

Comment: I'll believe it when I see a `[status-completed]` tag on my question.

Comment: @Juan [Good news, everyone!](http://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-exchange-podcast-episode-88)

Answer (score 3):

I've just finished to listen the [87th](http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode87-2010.04.15.mp3) final special XX episode today; simply great great podcast, I loved the content and the technical stuff told in their friendly and super communicative way.

I really hope they will restart soon with Alex Miller, Jeff and all the team; I've recently seen three of them at **11Mix** ([guest session video](http://ispss.istreamplanet.com/mix11/ch9day1/) @ 2:30) and I'm looking forward to listen to those guys again talking about Stack Exchange, cheesy technologies and so on.

Answer (score 1):

The podcasts started as effective advertising for Stack Overflow, and were ceased once the primary goal was accomplished.  It takes several hours to generate one, and quite frankly I'd rather have them put effort into making Stack Exchange better than performing a podcast.

Honestly, they were enjoyable, but not terribly informative.  While some of their positions may have changed over time, you can get a great idea of their personalities and perspectives simply by going back to the existing podcasts.  There are better podcasts out there.

If you really want them to bring the podcast back, I suspect you'll have to make a strong business case for it.

Comment: I disagree. I don't think that was the goal, and even if it was, it's not a good reason not to resume it (the goal can change now); also, I think they can handle making a podcast **and** making SE better, they are not mutually exclusive -- I'm sorry Mr Pollyanna, I upvoted a lot of your stuff, but this time it's a -1 from me, you don't deserve to be at 26120 reputation.

Comment: @Juan - That's ok, I make up 135% of the stuff I post, and then post it as though I actually know what I'm talking about. The additional 35% above 100% is due to material I make up and then don't post, and material that is subsequently deleted by me or others. I do try to use recycled material where possible, to lesson my impact on the environment, and while I'm cutting back on animal testing it turns out the animals that survive usually want seconds, so what can I do?

Comment: @Pollyanna: *"I make up 135% of the stuff I post"* -- Geez, don't tell everyone. You'll blow it for the rest of us.

Comment: your words can be so hurtful, Adam Davis.

Comment: @Jeff Like a really bad noogie from your cousin!

Comment: @Adam absolutely -1, saddest perspective of the podcast I've ever read.