# Remove the "podcast" link

Tags: feature-request, design

At the bottom of every SO/SE site is a set of links:

[image: Links]

The [podcast link](http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/series/stackoverflow.html) goes to the StackOverflow podcast page on IT Conversations. the most recent podacast is coming up for a year old.

Two options:

1. Remove the link
2. Record more podcasts *[(I vote for this)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79649/bring-back-the-podcast)*

Comment: with the title as is, -1 for me.  If option 2 was more the focus of the question, it would be +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The podcast is resumed, the first episode since it was stopped can be found on the stackoverflow blog:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/04/podcast-88/

The link should probably be changed to https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/ which shows the podcast related blog posts, although they should probably start sending them to http://blog.stackexchange.com/category/podcasts/

Also, as they are using soundcloud to host them, you can find an RSS feed of the podcast to point your music player at here:

http://feeds.soundcloud.com/users/4273388-stack-exchange/tracks

Answer (score 2):

The podcasts have resumed, but the podcast link still needs to be changed because they are no longer being distributed through IT Conversations.