# Update the podcast link in the footer

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, podcast, footer

I feel kinda bad posting this, because this came up in the "Related Questions" box on the ask page: [Remove the "podcast" link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81737/remove-the-podcast-link). But that's too localized now that the podcast is back.

As Adam said in his answer to that other question, the "podcast" link in the footer of every site should stop pointing to http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/series/stackoverflow.html and start pointing to http://blog.stackexchange.com/category/podcasts/.

It would be nice if the old SO blog posts about podcasts could be tagged `podcast`, too, for people who are actually looking for the old ones.

Comment: Change has been made - thanks for pointing out